# Run sudo as specific user without password

Tags: bash, unix, sudo

I used the following command in my script

```
sudo su - user -c bash <<EOF
cp /home/test.txt /opt/

EOF
```

If I use the `sudo su - user` on terminal, Unix don't ask me the Password but if I try to run the script the terminal ask me the Password and if I delete the EOF part the rest of code run when I quit the session.
I want to run the command in user mode sudo but the terminal don't Need ask me the Password.

If I use

```
sudo su - user <<EOF

code

EOF
```

I have an error in .bash_profile: too many argument

Answer (score 2):

> I want to run the command in user mode sudo but the terminal don't
>   Need ask me the Password.

The scenario you are experiencing is caused by the users cached credentials for sudo, which allow sudo to maintain a session and any further sudo command will not prompt for passwords.

**Check this:**

Open a new terminal and run `sudo whatever`, then close it and open another new terminal and run `sudo whatever`, you will see that `sudo` asks for password every time...

> If you still need to do that, then you have the following options:

**Prevent `sudo` to ask for password permanently**:

run `sudo visudo` and look for the line `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`, then add a line

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

then save and exit.

Note: This is a security risk

**Or Prevent `sudo` to ask for password permanently only for specific script**:

run `sudo visudo` and look for the line `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`, then add a line

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: path_to_the_script
```

then save and exit

**Provide password inside the script**, by running your `sudo` command like this:

```
sudo -S <<< "password" command
```

Note: This is a security risk too.

Comment: Why when I'm in the terminal with a specific user and I do the command sudo su - user2, enter normally in this user mode whitouth the Password? I want the bash do the same think because I Need after do a specific command but I Need to Switch in other user mode.

Comment: @andy89ch Have you checked it as how I specified? it doesn't work the way you are thinking it works... Just open a new terminal and run that command... `sudo` has it's own password requirement

Comment: If I try what you ask me, the terminal ask me always the password

Comment: @andy89ch, yes that's the expected behavior, running `sudo` without providing password is not allowed

Comment: Ok I know what you say but in my script if I write only the command sudo su - user and nothing else, Change correctly the mode of user without ask me the Password but I can after send the command via my script.

Comment: @andy89ch As I explained, your cached credentials are saved once you run a sudo command in a terminal. And if you run another command or script and if that script contains sudo command it will get the credential from cached credential and won't ask for password. So again, check it by running the script in a new terminal, and you will see...(where you haven't run any sudo command before the script)

Comment: ok but there are no solution to avoid this Problem?? Because if not I am blocked and I don't know which other solution to do.

Comment: @andy89ch The only option you have is to run it without `sudo` and `su` i.e as a normal user.

Comment: I know but in this way I don't have Access to the Folder where I Need to copy the file

Comment: @andy89ch another way (not recommended) is to prevent sudo to prompt for password at all...

Comment: @andy89ch or provide password like this: `echo 'password' | sudo -S command` It's a security risk though..

Comment: For the first user I don't Need the Password because I use the publickey to connect. There is a possibility to start an ssh Connection with the publickey?? so for avoid a Little bit the ask for the password

Comment: Last question, how I say before, with a normal command in my code as: sudo su - user and after cp /home/test.txt /opt/, the Change user work correctly whithout ask the Password but the command cp don't work just I quit the session. There is no possibility to run the command when I have changed correctly the user?

Comment: Really avoid to provide a password in the command line... and also with an echo.  It will persists in history too and in the process list for the execution time. At least use a string redirect.

Comment: @andy89ch `sudo su - user -c bash <<EOF` is too confusing. change it to:
`sudo -H -u user bash <<EOF`

Comment: @andy89ch it will ask for password (sudo is involved). If you want to prevent it then follow one of the methods I have specified. (second mehtod is the recommended way)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to execute your command as a different user. This might be your answer: [Run a shell script as another user that has no password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password)

```
sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c 'echo "I am $USER, with uid $UID"'
```

It is a quote from the link. Probably the following is better for you:

```
sudo -H -u otheruser bash <<EOF
cp /home/test.txt /opt/
EOF
```

**UPDATE:** You may wish to create a specific sudo rule to run a specific command without password (inside /etc/sudoers file -remember to use visudo to edit it-):

```
otheruser ALL=NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/your_command.sh
```

(of course you need root access to edit sudoers, I hope you can do it).
And create the script called `your_command.sh` that contains your logic. You'll then be allowed to run it without password:

```
sudo -H -u otheruser your_command.sh
```

I know, it's not a "single line command" but it is safe as it allows only one specific command without password. And it doesn't require a password, of course!

Comment: nothing Change, Unix ask me the Password. The Problem is I Need to Switch to this user

Comment: If it is safe and logical for your system you can use the NOPASSWD option of sudo.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
sudo passwd -d <username>
```

this command deleted the password for the specified user.

Answer (score -3):

Then don't use sudo, then it won't ask for password, but you will to be have logged in as root!

Comment: If I don't use sudo,Unix ask to me the Password always. I try all different command with sudo but the only one work withouth Password is sudo su - user